# Assign a document as main document

Tags: texmaker

In Texmaker is it possible to assign a tex document as main document such that its structure is always opened in the structure windows?
currently when I click on a tex document in the windows, it opened the tex document, at the same time the structure windows display the structure of the newly opened tex document rather than the original one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Options -> "Define Current Document as Master document".

And with one click or with the shortcut ctrl+shift+F2, you can toggle between the "master document" (with it's structure) and the current document :

[image]